# How to Change Mouse Pointer icon in Oracle forms 10g?

Tags: oracle, oracleforms

Is this possible to change the mouse pointer icon in oracle forms with the custom animated icon?
I am not searching for 
set_application_property(CURSOR_STYLE, 'HAND'
what is usually used?

Comment: SET_APPLICATION_PROPERTY is what is usually used.  I'm not aware that 'HAND' is a valid style to specify.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if you can set it to a custom animated icon. Oracle Forms 12 shows the below as being available:

> " The SET_ITEM_PROPERTY argument, CURSOR_STYLE is used to change the
>   mouse cursor (pointer) while hovering over an item. In earlier
>   versions, it was only possible to set the cursor style at the
>   application level. This resulted in the cursor appearing the same
>   regardless of where the mouse was pointed. The desired cursor can be
>   selected at design-time as an Item Property or at runtime in the
>   application pl/sql. Possible cursors are:
>
> DEFAULT » INSERTION » HAND » MOVE "» ARROW » BUSY » CROSSHAIR »

https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/forms/documentation/oracleforms-12210-newfeatures-2906037.pdf